# crash report and rejected by Apple

Tags: iphone

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
I have developed one app for my customer.
I tested it on devices(ipad/ipod touch) with ios 4.2, 4.3.2 3.1.3 under ios deployment target 3.0, 3.1.3, 4.2 
Every case worked well, I sent my customer the source code project.
They compiled on their mac and submitted to app store.
But Apple rejected the app with crash report

```
Incident Identifier: 292D9837-853C-4617-87A7-098DCC2B0033
CrashReporter Key:   e99f963e7b1eb7bdcb011bace61a214a69e1468f
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         AppName [8231]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F539E9F7-8470-4A79-B343-01E9148140FC/AppName.app/Zodiac
Identifier:      AppName
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-04-15 15:10:38.754 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.1 (8G4)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35b91a1c 0x35b80000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337e93b4 0x337b6000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337e1bf8 0x337b6000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35419a64 0x353d5000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30f6a06c 0x30f64000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35417e36 0x353d5000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35417e8a 0x353d5000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35417f5a 0x353d5000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30f68c84 0x30f64000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x368c148a 0x36823000 + 648330
10  CoreFoundation                  0x368c14c4 0x36823000 + 648388
11  UIKit                           0x3666da4c 0x36464000 + 2136652
12  UIKit                           0x3666ee02 0x36464000 + 2141698
13  UIKit                           0x365e85e2 0x36464000 + 1590754
14  UIKit                           0x365b5f9e 0x36464000 + 1384350
15  UIKit                           0x3649aeb8 0x36464000 + 224952
16  Zodiac                          0x00003b06 0x1000 + 11014
17  Zodiac                          0x0000410c 0x1000 + 12556
18  UIKit                           0x365e73c0 0x36464000 + 1586112
19  UIKit                           0x3666d95c 0x36464000 + 2136412
20  UIKit                           0x3666ee02 0x36464000 + 2141698
21  UIKit                           0x364994c6 0x36464000 + 218310
22  UIKit                           0x36493b02 0x36464000 + 195330
23  UIKit                           0x364687d0 0x36464000 + 18384
24  UIKit                           0x3646820e 0x36464000 + 16910
25  UIKit                           0x36467c4c 0x36464000 + 15436
26  GraphicsServices                0x3624be70 0x36247000 + 20080
27  CoreFoundation                  0x36898a90 0x36823000 + 481936
28  CoreFoundation                  0x3689a838 0x36823000 + 489528
29  CoreFoundation                  0x3689b606 0x36823000 + 493062
30  CoreFoundation                  0x3682bebc 0x36823000 + 36540
31  CoreFoundation                  0x3682bdc4 0x36823000 + 36292
32  UIKit                           0x36492d42 0x36464000 + 191810
33  UIKit                           0x36490800 0x36464000 + 182272
34  Zodiac                          0x00002cac 0x1000 + 7340
35  Zodiac                          0x00002c60 0x1000 + 7264

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35b923ec 0x35b80000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337ea6d8 0x337b6000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337eabbc 0x337b6000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35b92fbc 0x35b80000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33b97094 0x33b91000 + 24724
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33b9804a 0x33b91000 + 28746
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x33b9760a 0x33b91000 + 26122
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337ea58a 0x337b6000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337eabbc 0x337b6000 + 215996

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35b8fc00 0x35b80000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35b8f758 0x35b80000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x368992b8 0x36823000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3689b562 0x36823000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3682bebc 0x36823000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3682bdc4 0x36823000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x34993292 0x3498d000 + 25234
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337e930a 0x337b6000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337eabb4 0x337b6000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3f46948c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x001adfec      r7: 0x2fdfde00
    r8: 0x3fab9964    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x001af500     r11: 0x3676fd97
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfddf4      lr: 0x337e93bb      pc: 0x35b91a1c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x6fff +Zodiac armv7  <cd2e60f4c590d2202961c3ebf829e12e> /var/mobile/Applications/F539E9F7-8470-4A79-B343-01E9148140FC/AppName.app/AppName
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <8dbdf7bab30e355b81e7b2e333d5459b> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30f02000 - 0x30f0bfff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30f50000 - 0x30f55fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x30f64000 - 0x31028fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <f855251d90a53bdbb5d5a39fdbde6d9b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x31157000 - 0x31157fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3119c000 - 0x311bcfff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x312ce000 - 0x31305fff  Security armv7  <163414ba17df347ca76088015010e2c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x313b1000 - 0x313b1fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x313cd000 - 0x31400fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31474000 - 0x31482fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f02d1c50f0f33991adb1a2caed02eb77> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3178a000 - 0x318defff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x319a7000 - 0x319edfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <4319daea186b3a22b148ca78000f11ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x31a83000 - 0x31a87fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <36e96d0a7dda330281a43172d0ada49a> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x31a91000 - 0x31ae2fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x31bcd000 - 0x31ce7fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x337b6000 - 0x33837fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <caa1846ad2583d1b84c1a15c50c126a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x33b91000 - 0x33b9efff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <6c4eeb08757b365f8429ef6747f89ad3> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x33b9f000 - 0x33bbcfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x33bed000 - 0x33c2afff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33d96000 - 0x33db5fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x33db6000 - 0x33deefff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33e23000 - 0x33e23fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <68322643de8030978c862de530055bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x340c1000 - 0x340c4fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x340c5000 - 0x340defff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x340df000 - 0x340e6fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x340e7000 - 0x340e9fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x34323000 - 0x34328fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <1eaf25ddd98e3a249bca536671c5819d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x34381000 - 0x34386fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x34416000 - 0x34458fff  CoreAudio armv7  <d45e275525ef3c32b36e0f1020cad705> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x344c2000 - 0x344ebfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x344ec000 - 0x34595fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x346be000 - 0x346edfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x34704000 - 0x34711fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x348b6000 - 0x348b6fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3492e000 - 0x3498cfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d3f7360687333cad987890c314ae0d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3498d000 - 0x34f98fff  WebCore armv7  <b25d7d87ebd235ecbceca611a063c73b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x34f9d000 - 0x34fa8fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3501b000 - 0x35070fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x35209000 - 0x35328fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x353d5000 - 0x3541ffff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x35420000 - 0x35422fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x35423000 - 0x35424fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x35441000 - 0x354b0fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x354f1000 - 0x355a2fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x355a3000 - 0x355a8fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <a19b1caf96c73568b14a1660f147ae2f> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x35762000 - 0x3584ffff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3596a000 - 0x3599ffff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x359ab000 - 0x359affff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x359b5000 - 0x359f1fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <79d00adb09de3da991ed21f48f27adb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x35a3d000 - 0x35a3efff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x35b61000 - 0x35b6dfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x35b80000 - 0x35b97fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <29eb602b615b3c3b95722868100a2d1c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35ee2000 - 0x35ee3fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x35ee5000 - 0x35eeafff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x35fc0000 - 0x35ff8fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x36006000 - 0x36009fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <0479a171c00d3f629d639713acb72b5b> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3600a000 - 0x3601ffff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x36127000 - 0x36128fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3618d000 - 0x3623cfff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x36247000 - 0x36253fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c508734deb43352782433a290ff235bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x363c8000 - 0x363cafff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x363d2000 - 0x36411fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <b5735b0f3dba32c087c5b58aa48ae592> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x36412000 - 0x36418fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x36464000 - 0x367f1fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x36821000 - 0x36822fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <5f077c4d204d3cd7b04452c42d41f763> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x36823000 - 0x36908fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <4f643539f91f330790f112ea7150b3a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3696e000 - 0x36970fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36b9f000 - 0x36b9ffff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x36c39000 - 0x36f20fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <652c97e211553d4e84968a61f62a0ac5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x36f21000 - 0x36f25fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <2c61a8f7e7bf32d890e957d768d769ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x37078000 - 0x3710dfff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3710e000 - 0x371cdfff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x37215000 - 0x3721cfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x373f3000 - 0x37514fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <54e27b8aa66c32b48ffeadadcc514331> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x37560000 - 0x37664fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <f63386018d703534b766514e4bbbd1d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
```

I try to duplicate the crash on my device(ipad/ipod touch) but no result.
I just wonder if there is any difference between my mac and my customer's mac causes the error happened.

**Update:**
after got the suggestion from here, I dragged the crash log to Organizer and got the translated result:

```
Incident Identifier: 292D9837-853C-4617-87A7-098DCC2B0033
CrashReporter Key:   e99f963e7b1eb7bdcb011bace61a214a69e1468f
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         MyAppName [8231]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F539E9F7-8470-4A79-B343-01E9148140FC/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
Identifier:      MyAppName
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-04-15 15:10:38.754 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.1 (8G4)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35b91a1c 0x35b80000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337e93b4 0x337b6000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337e1bf8 0x337b6000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3085ea64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30f6a06c 0x30f64000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3085ce36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3085ce8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3085cf5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30f68c84 0x30f64000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x368c148a 0x36823000 + 648330
10  CoreFoundation                  0x368c14c4 0x36823000 + 648388
11  UIKit                           0x361b2a4c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1104
12  UIKit                           0x361b3e02 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 86
13  UIKit                           0x3612d5e2 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 30
14  UIKit                           0x360faf9e -[UIViewController loadView] + 74
15  UIKit                           0x35fdfeb8 -[UIViewController view] + 24
16  MyAppName                           0x00003b06 0x1000 + 11014
17  MyAppName                           0x0000410c 0x1000 + 12556
18  UIKit                           0x3612c3c0 -[UIViewController awakeFromNib] + 28
19  UIKit                           0x361b295c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 864
20  UIKit                           0x361b3e02 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 86
21  UIKit                           0x35fde4c6 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 90
22  UIKit                           0x35fd8b02 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 174
23  UIKit                           0x35fad7d0 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1108
24  UIKit                           0x35fad20e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
25  UIKit                           0x35facc4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
26  GraphicsServices                0x3624be70 0x36247000 + 20080
27  CoreFoundation                  0x36898a90 0x36823000 + 481936
28  CoreFoundation                  0x3689a838 0x36823000 + 489528
29  CoreFoundation                  0x3689b606 0x36823000 + 493062
30  CoreFoundation                  0x3682bebc 0x36823000 + 36540
31  CoreFoundation                  0x3682bdc4 0x36823000 + 36292
32  UIKit                           0x35fd7d42 -[UIApplication _run] + 366
33  UIKit                           0x35fd5800 UIApplicationMain + 664
34  MyAppName                           0x00002cac 0x1000 + 7340
35  MyAppName                           0x00002c60 0x1000 + 7264
```

The crash happened at thread0, step 35, mem address 0x00002c60 
So I called command atos to locate the crash point as below:

```
atos -arch armv6 -o MyAppName.app/MyAppName 0x00002c60
```

it returns

```
-[AppDelegate setGPictureArray1:] (in MyAppName) (AppDelegate.m:9)
```

I show all codes before the line

```
//AppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"
@class RootViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet RootViewController *rootViewController;
    NSMutableArray * gPictureArray1; 
    NSMutableArray * gPictureArray2; 

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * gPictureArray1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * gPictureArray2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *rootViewController;
@end

 //AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize rootViewController;
@synthesize gPictureArray1;//**it looks like the crash happens here**
@synthesize gPictureArray2;
```

Welcome any comment.

Comment: I take it you've tried release builds on all your supported hardware as well as just default?

Comment: you need to symbolicate the crash logs before anyone will be able to help you. See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports -- also note that you need to follow these instructions on the mac where the build was created

Comment: While you are waiting to have the log symbolicate, have your customer send you an Ad-Hoc build of what they submitted to the App Store.

Comment: Just repeating @Asad to emphasize: you have to symbolicate that report before you'll have enough information to even begin to guess at the problem. Follow the link, symbolicate your crash report, and then if you can't figure it out from the results (it will give you meaningful error messages, not this useless framework + memory offset stuff), come back here and paste the symbolicated report.

Comment: so, does it mean I have to get the symbolicate file on customer's mac?

Comment: It looks like need the .dSYM file while create the released app file. Is it right?

Comment: I try to follow the instruction in the link above and use atos to locate crash point

Comment: but it said that 'atos cannot load symbols for the file MyAppName.app.dSYM'

Comment: finally it worked, I have update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tested it on devices(ipad/ipod touch)

An ipad, or ipod touch isn't an iphone.

> Hardware Model: iPhone3,1

Comment: Apple have given me the same crash report on ipod touch

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that customer missed a xib file which caused the app crashing